# Create PDF layers using DomPDF

Tags: pdf, layer, dompdf

I'm trying to create a PDF with layers, one for the texts and the other for a background image so user can print only the text layer.

Does anyone knows if it's possible and if so, how can I do that ?

I'm using version 0.8.2.

Thanks

Comment: Question 1: Is it possible to create an OCG layer for text that is shown on the screen *and* printed, and an OCG layer for images that is shown on the screen and *not* printed? **Yes, that's possible if you define Optional Content Groups (OCG).** Question 2: Is it possible with DomPDF? **We don't know. What have you tried?** I don't down-vote people with a reputation of 1, but I see that you already have one down-vote. Please read http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ to find out why you might have gotten that down-vote. (It's also the reason why I vote to close this question.)

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to specify in my question content "using DomPDF" I put it only in the title. I know it is possible to have layers in a PDF so my question is about how to achieve that using DomPDF.

Comment: I have tried using two <body> but it creates two different pages, I also tried with different CSS @media but it hides the image on the PDF preview . I have been looking some info on different forums but I have not found any information about how to do that with DomPDF. So wonder if anyone has any idea on how to create two different layers with DomPDF it would be grate...  Thanks

Comment: Does DomPDF allows the use of custom tags the way iText does: https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-5-custom-tag-workers-and-css-appliers Because you won't be able to achieve this with regular HTML only. Also: please add what you've tried to the question instead of mentioning it in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Finally it looks like layers or the Optional Content Groups are not supported by DomPDF. So my solution was to change to TCPDF, it's not great for CSS but it offers the option to create layers and change the visibility of objects in the PDF.
So you can set objects to show only in screen or print.

I hope this can help if someone has the same issue.

[Here's the link to TCPDF](https://tcpdf.org/)